# Rails Postgres reconnection on failover for RDS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, activerecord, amazon-rds

I have a Rails application with a Postgres database under AWS RDS with multi-az architecture. The HA architecture used by RDS is master/slave and they provide the service with a single endpoint that points to the current master.

Whenever there's a database failover, Active Record will continue to try to connect to the same server, instead of retrying the connection in order to pick up the new IP for the master.

Is there a way to create a "global" rescue for the `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ConnectionBad: PQsocket() can't get socket descriptor` error that simply runs `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect!` that will make the next query to work?

Comment: I /think/ the problem here is `reset` on the postgres connection doesn't do a new DNS lookup but not positive. This means the connection has to be destroyed and recreated. RDS Postgres does a DNS failover.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to make Active Record reconnect after the failover event by applying a monkey patch to `postgres_adapter`.

`lib/core_ext/active_record/postgresql_adapter.rb`:

```
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter'

class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter
  private
  def exec_no_cache(sql, name, binds)
    log(sql, name, binds) { @connection.async_exec(sql, []) }
  rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid => e
    if e.to_s.include?('PG::ConnectionBad')
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect!
    end
    raise e
  end
end
```